# How to run a command like it is run in another directory?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, if I want o run `make` in `../../dir1`, I can do `make -C ../../dir1`.

Likewise, I want to run a command `mkitb` like it is called in directory `..`. How can I do that? (I want to stay in current directory without doing `cd ..` before running `mkitb`.)